# Probability of filling M boxes with 2 or more elements when sampling S elements from N total elements

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling

Similar to this question, [Frequency of Item in Combination](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229044/frequency-of-item-in-combination).

I am randomly sampling S objects out of N=99 objects into 9 boxes labeled by a single character, "A-I". **Question 1: I want to find the probability of M boxes having 2 or more objects, dependent on how many objects I sample, S out of N.** Currently I am only able to do so by simulation (see code below), which is RNG dependent, but accurate. **Question 2: Is there a distribution I can follow here?** I'm bouncing between binomial and hypergeometric, but I am uncertain how to implement it.

```
mycountL <- double(9)
names(mycountL) <- LETTERS[1:9]

# Change this for sample drawing size
xTimes = 18

set.seed(12)
for(i in 1:10000){
  nL <- names(which(table(sample(rep(LETTERS[1:9],11), xTimes ))>=2))
  lL <- length(nL)
  mycountL[lL] <- mycountL[lL]+1
}

mycountL/10000 #For probabilities. Drawing 18 times is the lowest sample possible to draw exactly 2 in each LETTER, except that it is highly unlikely.
```

#### Edits: Clarification

Comment: This is not simple.  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410506/919 I show how to solve this problem using the smaller example of M=2 with 99 replaced by 5 and 9 replaced by 6.

Comment: I somewhat understand the mathematics but implementing it is another challenge altogether. I'm afraid I can't wrap my head around your "first" step.

Comment: If it helps, thing of that step as just being two applications of the `tabulate` function.